# ASP.NET MVC 4 Templates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, themes

I want to know if there is such concept in MVC4 (or other versions) like "Theme". I'am a total newbie using MVC, but I have some experience making simple Wordpress websites, using cool themes available on the web. Is there a way to get themes for my MVC project? I mean, some custom views and CSS, that can help with front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link will help you. You can plug these into your MVC app to get you going [bootstrap skins](https://startbootstrap.com/)